# Programmatically change PSMultiValueSpecifier values

Tags: objective-c, settings.bundle, root.plist

I have a setting bundle where I'd like to show list of Albums available in the gallery as PSMultiValueSpecifier type. I am done with most of the things with Settings Bundle but the challenge I am facing is updating settings bundle PSMultiValueSpecifier if new albums is added into gallery by user.

Can anyone shed some lights on it?

For reference you may check out livebooth application setting bundle
Also find image at https://i.stack.imgur.com/2clIG.jpg for reference

Comment: I managed to do it by explicitly writting back root.plist with updated settings dictionary.

Comment: If you've found a solution you should add it as an answer and accept it.